# Complex JSON object with array does not map to Web API Model?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2

The following JSON object does map correctly.  It maps all the fields to my Web API model except the partNumbersReturned array.  Does the model on the Web API have to look different?  Here is the JSON object:

```
$scope.carbForm =
            {
                ownerInformation:
                {
                    fullName: "",
                    email: "",
                    street1: "",
                    street2: "",
                    city: "",
                    state: "",
                    zip: ""
                },
                newOwnerInformation:
                {
                    fullName: "",
                    email: "",
                    street1: "",
                    street2: "",
                    city: "",
                    state: "",
                    zip: ""
                },
                vehicleInformation: {
                    vin: "",
                    vehicleMake: "",
                    vehicleModel: "",
                    vehicleYear: ""
                },
                productInformation: {
                    productStatus: "",
                    otherExplanation: "",
                    partNumbersReturned: []
                }
            };
```

Here is my Web API Model:

```
public class CarbForm
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public VehicleInformation VehicleInformation { get; set; }
    public OwnerInformation OwnerInformation { get; set; }
    public NewOwnerInformation NewOwnerInformation { get; set; }
    public ProductInformation ProductInformation { get; set; }
}
```

The ProductInformation is defined like this:

```
public class ProductInformation
{
    public string ProductStatus { get; set; }
    public string OtherExplanation { get; set; }
    public List<string> PartNumbersReturned { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you might be using Angular on the client side? Ensure that you are properly serializing your object before posting to your API by making use of  **JSON.stringify()**. Example:

```
$http({
        url: '/helloWorld/',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(yourObject),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      })
};
```